# Facing deployment & diff issues with VSCode SFDX CLI

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, command-line-interface, sfdx, salesforce-sfdx

When I am trying to deploy any file, I am getting `Connection has no instanceUrl.` Although In the JSON file I checked the instanceUrl is there, also I am facing issues with the diff which is taking longer than expected.

```
12:06:54.465 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias futureCRDev --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
(node:7741) Warning: Deprecated environment variable: SFDX_JSON_TO_STDOUT. Please use SF_JSON_TO_STDOUT instead.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Warning: The "force auth web login" command has been deprecated. Use "org login web" instead.
Warning: The "--setalias" flag has been deprecated. Use "--alias | -a" instead.
Warning: The "--instanceurl" flag has been deprecated. Use "--instance-url | -r" instead.
Warning: The "--setdefaultusername" flag has been deprecated. Use "--set-default | -s" instead.
Successfully authorized somya.tiwari@salesforce.com.futurdev with org ID 00D2f0000000wReEAI
12:07:14.808 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias futureCRDev --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
 ended with exit code 0

12:07:24.468 Starting SFDX: Deploy Source to Org

Connection has no instanceUrl.
```